# Publish Azure Open AI webapp

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-openai

I've developed a simple chatbot using Azure Open AI Studio. I deployed it as a web app, accessible via example.azurewebsites.net. However, it only works when I'm signed into Azure. If I share the link, it requires a sign-in.

How can I make it completely accessible to anyone with the link?

I've tinkered with the authentication settings but haven't had any success.

Answer (score -1):

Hi to make your web app public and accessible without requiring a sign-in, follow these steps:
Sign in to the Azure Portal.
Select your App Service (web app).
Go to the "Authentication" settings.
Turn off or set "App Service Authentication" to "Off."
Set "Action to take when request is not authenticated" to "Allow anonymous requests (no action)."
Save your configuration.
Restart your web app.
Ensure your chatbot's code doesn't have additional authentication restrictions.
Test access in an incognito/private browsing window to confirm accessibility to anyone without sign-in.

Comment: not working? you know additional settings for that ?